# Google Maps | I cannot add multiple Markers on the map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create a simple Google Maps API, that allowing the end user to add some Markers on the map.

The problem is, that while I can add the markers in programmaticaly level, the markers are not appering on the map.

This is the code that adding the markers on the map:

```
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
{
    var markerLatLng    =   new google.maps.LatLng(points[i].lat(), points[i].lng());
    var marker          =   new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            position        :   markerLatLng,
            map             :   map,
            zIndex          :   (10000 + i),
            icon            :   {
                url         :   'http://www.saronikoscity.gr/site/images/ico_web.gif',
                size        :   new google.maps.Size(16, 16, 'px', 'px')
            }
        }
    );

    markerRegistry.push(marker);
}
```

Here you can see a live example of what I mean : http://jsfiddle.net/merianos/n4wjw/

What can be wrong with that ? Do you see anything wrong ?

**Note** : I have try to add a single Marker on my map, and in this case it is working normaly. The issue comes with the multiple Markers.

Kind regards

Comment: In your example you defined functions inside $(document).ready(function(){---})...Its wrong.Also there are no values set for variables

Comment: Oop !!! I didn't knew that. Anyway, do you beleave that can harm my script ?

Comment: Your wish its your code.But this is not the place to define functions in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply defining `var map` twice, check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n4wjw/2/) for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
var markers = [
    ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
    ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
    ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
    ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
    ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];


function initializeMaps() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"),myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(
    function($)
    {
        if($('#myMap').length > 0)
        {
            initializeMaps();
        }
    }
);
```